# How to link Tomcat container to Oracle container

Tags: oracle, docker, tomcat

Im setting up 2 contaienrs 
1st container : Tomcat
2nd container : Oracle DATABASE

I make a network Bridge for this two containers, and my .war app still unworking!

There is any solution to make tomcat container read and display data from oracle database container?

Comment: Show your compose file

Comment: i don't have any compose file! If this file is required, can i get a configuration example for  tomcat and oracle database.

Comment: I was asking for `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: yes, i don't have any docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Then why have you added the `docker-compose` tag to this question? Or the `docker-swarm` tag for that matter?

Comment: I said maybe those files are required to make my 2 containers communicate

Comment: What commands are you actually running?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I Start tomcat container and oracle container, and they work properly, but when i access to my module localhost:8082/lounge, it show nothing for me and no error message show for me.

Comment: <Resource   auth="Container" 
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
  global="jdbc/vimsDs"    
  initialSize="10" maxActive="100" maxWait="10000" minIdle="10" 
  username="**"
  name="jdbc/vimsDs"    
  password="**" 
  removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="36000" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
this is the config in tomcat server.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution wich is i installed a container tomcat 7.0.90 with open-jdk-7
and my application is require with open-jdk-8. that's why is not working,

when i installed the open-jdk-8, its work correctly!

Answer (score 1):

This db url is pointing to your localhost (tomcat box)

`url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"`

If your oracle box ip is 198.0.68.10 then change it to:

`url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@198.0.68.10:1521:XE"`

You can also use telnet to make sure you can connect to the database box from the tomcat box:

`telnet database-box-ip-address-or-name 1521`

If you see 'connection failed' then the database is not running or not accessible. If the screen clears and you see some kind of response, you're all set.

Comment: I test it with Telnet oracle-box-ip-adress 1521 and it show for me this message "Trying 172.19.0.3...
Connected to 172.19.0.3.
Escape character is '^]'".
Also i test in the tomcat container with this command curl http://172.19.0.3:8080 to connect to database and it work properly. But that module in tomcat server still unworking.